# [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: java, list, netbeans, classcastexception, toarray

The following code (run in netbeans) always gives me a ClassCastException in the last line:

```
private void GetModules() throws SQLException {
    stm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM module");
    Rs = stm.executeQuery();
    Lliste.clear();
    modules.clear();
    while (Rs.next()) {
        String[] str_l = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            str_l[i] = Rs.getString(i + 1);
        Lliste.add(str_l);
        modules.add(str_l[1]);
    }
    stm.close();
    Rs.close();
    liste.setListData((String[]) modules.toArray());
}
```

when I run the code, I get the following Error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

I tried also to not cast it but it gives me an error.
Could someone please help me? I'm really confused with this!

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you probably shouldn't be running this piece of code from the EDT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the overloaded [List.toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray-T:A-) method that specifies the return type of the array :

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

In this way :

```
liste.setListData(modules.toArray(new String[modules.size()]);
```

Comment: idk why downvoted, reply seems correct, I would only add that you should use empty array as argument for initialization: `list.toArray(new String[0]);`
see more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53285440/4270929